# Set audio format in liblvc

Tags: c++, libvlc, audioformat

How can I set the format of an audio in libvlc?

there is a function in libvlc for it but I don't know how to use it[[from here]](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gaf7af18f5f09e34234e5f1bf4681dfe43):

```
LIBVLC_API void libvlc_audio_set_format (   libvlc_media_player_t *     mp,
const char *    format,
unsigned    rate,
unsigned    channels 
)
```

> Set decoded audio format.
>
> This only works in combination with libvlc_audio_set_callbacks(), and
>   is mutually exclusive with libvlc_audio_set_format_callbacks().
>
> Parameters mp the media player format a four-characters string
>   identifying the sample format (e.g. "S16N" or "FL32") rate    sample rate
>   (expressed in Hz) channels    channels count Version LibVLC 2.0.0 or
>   later

How can I set the format of audio file, for example a wav file?

Comment: Ali will help you for sure

Answer (score 2):

This API is for raw, decoded audio, which is typically forwarded to speakers or re-encoded to store it.

This API is **NOT** to export audio as files (unless you implement that yourself in your app, that is). To convert files, see the stream output MRL command-line syntax, as there is currently no designated libvlc API available for use-case.